# MySQL Server on Windows XP SP3 Installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I am currently trying to install MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows XP Professional. The only firewall on the computer is the Windows Firewall which I have disabled.

I am going through the MySQL Server configuration and it completes the starting service section but when it tries to apply security settings an error is displayed saying

'The security settings could not be applied to the database because the connection has failed with the following error.

Error Nr. 1045
Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO).

I have set up a password for the root account during the configuration wizard of the server and the Windows firewall is disabled. I have tried uninstalling MySQL Server, deleting the MySQL Server in program files, rebooting and trying to reinstall but I still get the same error.

Thanks for your help with this problem.

Comment: download and install WAMP save yourself some pain

Comment: that's not any good for what I want because I need mysql database for C# software development inside Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is sort of solved. For some reason MySQL Server 5.5 comes up with the error saying that a firewall is blocking the security settings settings from being applied even when the firewall is disabled.

However if you install MySQL Server 5.1 there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems during installation and the error is `MySQL Error Nr. 1045`, it means you've done the previous MySQL installation and that the computer system has been read and has saved MySQL files.

What you need to do is:

1. Uninstall MySQL through the control panel
2. Delete the MySQL folder in `C:\Program Files`
3. Delete the MySQL folder in the directory `documents and settings`

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to delete all data from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL` then run **mysql server instance configuration wizard** from **Start Menu** and reconfig the server 
you might remove current instance first